# About C documentation

Tags: c, eclipse

Coming from Java environment, I feel I got spoiled a lot when it comes to documentation. In C, using Eclipse, mouseover `putchar()` shows:

```
__CRT_INLINE int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW putchar(int __c)
{
  return (--stdout->_cnt >= 0)
    ?  (int) (unsigned char) (*stdout->_ptr++ = (char)__c)
    :  _flsbuf (__c, stdout);}
```

While all this is terrific, I was wondering if any IDE includes more information about the specifics of what a given function does, ie, "prints a character to the output device"? Something similar to [this](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/putchar/) as part of an IDE would be awesome.

Is there a way to get this level of detailed as part of Eclipse or any other IDE?

The question, obviously is not about `putchar()`, but rather is about a general approach to documentation using C programming language.

Comment: not part of an IDE, but you can always use `man putchar`

Comment: You mean something like this? http://www.eclipse.org/linuxtools/projectPages/libhover/

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All credit goes to Let_Me_Be.

The following [link](http://eclipse.org/linuxtools/projectPages/libhover) provides a complete solution to what i was looking for

**eclipse.org/linuxtools/projectPages/libhover**

Answer (score 1):

NetBeans will show you the man page inline: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/navigating-editing.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution for eclipse or an IDE, but my approach usually involves googling the function's manpage. eg, `man putchar`, which you've already found.

I'll also suggest this, at the risk of downvotes: The IBM C documentation is, in my experience, *really good*. Often it has real working understandable code examples and everything.

Now, IBM C is different from GNU C, so there are differences or features that do not apply to gcc. That said, Take a look at [its page on the putchar() function](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r10.bpxbd00/putc.htm).

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of things to complain about in  **[C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf)**, but it is still the authoritative reference and imo the best source for answers to the question, "what does it do?"

MS Visual Studio wraps a little skin around the C99 bones.

And MSDN goes further: docs on MSDN are beginning actually to resemble real papers by real writers that communicate useful info to a wide audience of neophytes and pros alike.